# Reset MSI on App Service?

Tags: azure-managed-identity

Is there any way to redo MSI configuration on an App Service?

I deleted the service principal in AD not realising it was for MSI so of course when I try to use MSI it cannot find it.   If I disable/re-enable MSI it says it is registering in AD but does nothing.   I have even tried deleting the MSI environment variables before disable/re-enable - the environment variables are regenerated (with a new SECRET value) but it still looks for the original service principal.

Comment: Also tried: 
1. Deleting identity block using Resource Explorer - change does not stick,
2. Cloning site to a slot then swapping slots - when I turn MSI back on it sets identity to the original service principal

Comment: 3. Deleting the App Service, recreating with the same name - MSI still trying to use original service principal.

Comment: Hi - I'm on the App Service team. There's a known issue here. Several folks have reported it. We're looking into a possible caching issue in the ARM layer that makes the principalID persist across creations. There's also investigation into the disablement issue. Hope to have a solution/answer soon.